# Django model_to_dict stack overflow crash

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, stack-overflow

In my app, I use a common `Base` model for all my models. I'v encountered a behaviour I can't explain with the `Campus` and `Hall` models:

```py
class Base(models.Model):
    id: int = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._initial = self.as_dict

    ...
    @property
    def as_dict(self) -> dict:
        fields = [field.name for field in self._meta.fields]
        res = model_to_dict(self, fields=fields)
        return res
    ...

class Campus(Base):
    name: str = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "campuses"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Hall(Base):
    name: str = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    campus: Campus = models.ForeignKey(Campus, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.campus is not None and isinstance(self.campus, str):
            self.campus = Campus.objects.get_or_create(name=self.campus)[0]
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}{f' ({self.campus})' if self.campus else ''}"
```

On the admin console, when I try to delete a certain `Campus` instance, the server crashes. This is a very small part of the (very long) trace:

```
Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
...
Current thread 0x00000bdc (most recent call first):
...
  File "P:\Python\Coursist\academic_helper\models\base.py", line 142 in as_dict
  File "P:\Python\Coursist\academic_helper\models\base.py", line 98 in __init__
  File "C:\Venvs\Coursist\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 512 in from_db
  File "C:\Venvs\Coursist\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 75 in __iter__
  File "C:\Venvs\Coursist\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1261 in _fetch_all
  File "C:\Venvs\Coursist\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 258 in __len__
  File "C:\Venvs\Coursist\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 411 in get
  File "C:\Venvs\Coursist\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 627 in refresh_from_db
  File "C:\Venvs\Coursist\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query_utils.py", line 139 in __get__
  File "C:\Venvs\Coursist\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 931 in value_from_object
  File "C:\Venvs\Coursist\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 93 in model_to_dict
  File "P:\Python\Coursist\academic_helper\models\base.py", line 142 in as_dict
  File "P:\Python\Coursist\academic_helper\models\base.py", line 98 in __init__
  File "C:\Venvs\Coursist\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 512 in from_db
  File "C:\Venvs\Coursist\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 75 in __iter__
  File "C:\Venvs\Coursist\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1261 in _fetch_all
  File "C:\Venvs\Coursist\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 258 in __len__
  File "C:\Venvs\Coursist\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 411 in get
  File "C:\Venvs\Coursist\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 627 in refresh_from_db
  File "C:\Venvs\Coursist\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query_utils.py", line 139 in __get__
  File "C:\Venvs\Coursist\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 931 in value_from_object
  File "C:\Venvs\Coursist\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 93 in model_to_dict
  File "P:\Python\Coursist\academic_helper\models\base.py", line 142 in as_dict
  File "P:\Python\Coursist\academic_helper\models\base.py", line 98 in __init__
  File "C:\Venvs\Coursist\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 512 in from_db
  File "C:\Venvs\Coursist\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 75 in __iter__
...
```

At first I thought it is some kind of circular pointing issue between `Hall` and `Campus`, but that doesn't seem to be the case (when debugging, I can't see any pointer from `Campus` to a `Hall`). The weird thing is that if I first delete all `Hall` instances, the deletion of the `Campus` goes smoothly.
I'm using `python 3.7` and `Django 3.0.6`

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging, I came up with this patch:

```py
class Base(models.Model):
    id: int = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if models.DEFERRED in args:
            # This means we delete it now, not interested in dict logic
            self._initial = dict()
        else:
            self._initial = self.as_dict
...
```

Not sure this is an elegant/correct solution, but it solved this bug and everything else seems to work fine.
If anyone else has any better ideas I would love to hear.

Answer (score 0):

Your design of BaseModel is causing this problem, because `model_to_dict` will resolve *ToMany relations and create possibly huge lists. This is amplified by the admin creating it's own in-memory list to show you all the related models you are about to delete.

You are basically putting a serialized representation on the model in it's init method, which you already have as a property. If this is your way of caching the value, then I suggest you use `django.utils.functions.cached_property` and change the mechanism to "cache at first access" rather than "cache at init":

```py
from django.utils.functional import cached_property


class Base(models.Model):
    id: int = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    ...
    @cached_property
    def as_dict(self) -> dict:
        fields = [field.name for field in self._meta.fields]
        res = model_to_dict(self, fields=fields)
        return res

    @property
    def _initial(self) -> dict:
        # if you're set on the _initial name
        return self.as_dict
```

Comment: Your reasoning makes sence, but the thing is that I use the `as_dict` method in `save` in order to determine if the object has changed since it was created, by comparing it to the `_inital` state. As I don't really care about performance issues, I'm wondering how to do this elegantly.

Comment: It depends on the reason: if you want to prevent a save when calling save, that's a bad pattern. If you want to have rollback / historic / diff information, then perhaps [temporal tables](https://pgxn.org/dist/temporal_tables/) may be something to look into. I've looked into alternatives, but I don't see a way either, if you need this to work at the model level (at the form level, has_changed() can be used). One optimization you could do is to not traverse *ToMany, but that may violate application requirements.